# Show a div between jquery getjson data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is :

```
var el = document.getElementById("showcontent");
        $.getJSON('ajaxdbtest.php', function(data) { 
            $.each(data, function(n, theData) {
                el.innerHTML += '<p>'+theData.name+'</p>';
            });
        });
```

The code returns the data ok. There are 40 results. I want to be able to add a custom div in between the results. So after every 5 results i want to add my custom div.

`<div id="mycustomdiv">Custom DIV</div>`

How can i do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're using an odd mix of jQuery and native JS methods. I'd suggest sticking to one or the other.

To achieve what you require using jQuery you can use the index of the current element in the set (your `n` variable holds this value) and the modulo operator to know when each 5 has passed. Try this:

```
var $el = $("#showcontent");

$.getJSON('ajaxdbtest.php', function(data) { 
    var $target = $el
    $.each(data, function(n, theData) {
        if (n % 5 == 0 && n != 0)
            $target = $('<div />').appendTo($el);

        $target.append('<p>' + theData.name + '</p>');
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/umtoga6L/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Working fine https://jsfiddle.net/umtoga6L/1/ only problem is that its showing at the start of the results too. I want it to start only after the first 5 results and loop after every 5 results.

Comment: You just need to check it's not the first item: `if (n % 5 == 0 && n != 0)`. You'll also need to amend the logic which determines which element gets appended to. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Thanks heaps mate! I used it in Framework7 and it works like a charm.

Comment: would appreciate if you point some docs to read for me to understand this better. thanks.